# when to use expm1 instead of exp in java

Tags: java, double-precision, exp

I am confused about using expm1 function in java
The Oracle java doc for Math.expm1 says:

> Returns exp(x) -1. Note that for values of x near 0, the exact sum of
>   expm1(x) + 1 is much closer to the true result of ex than exp(x).

but [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-math2/index.html) says:

> However, for negative values of x, roughly -4 and lower, the algorithm
>   used to calculate Math.exp() is relatively ill-behaved and subject to
>   round-off error. It's more accurate to calculate ex - 1 with a
>   different algorithm and then add 1 to the final result.

should we use expm1(x) for negative x values or near 0 values?

Comment: You can always pull some other algorithm off the net and use it.  No need to confine yourself to Java's library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The implementation of `double` at the bit level means that you can store `double`s near 0 with much more precision than `double`s near 1.  That's why `expm1` can give you much more accuracy for near-zero powers than `exp` can, because `double` doesn't have enough precision to store very accurate numbers very close to `1`.

I don't believe the article you're citing is correct, as far as the accuracy of `Math.exp` goes (modulo the limitations of `double`).  The `Math.exp` specification guarantees that the result is within 1 ulp of the exact value, which means -- to oversimplify a bit -- a relative error of at most 2^-52, ish.

Answer (score 8):

You use `expm1(x)` for anything close to 0. Positive or negative.

The reason is because `exp(x)` of anything close to 0 will be very close to 1. Therefore `exp(x) - 1` will suffer from destructive cancellation when `x` is close to 0.

`expm1(x)` is properly optimized to avoid this destructive cancellation.

---

From the mathematical side: If `exp` is implemented using its Taylor Series, then `expm1(x)` can be done by simply omitting the first `+1`.

Comment: But that page says: "roughly -4 and lower", does lower means here negative values close to 0 or smaller negative values?

Comment: @Masood_mj I actually disagree with that statement. It seems that the author is confusing two different sources of numerical instability in the taylor expansion of `exp(x)`. If you apply the series directly to large negative numbers, then yes the it will be unstable. So in practice you flip `x` positive and take the reciprocal at the end. But I can't imagine that `Math.exp(x)` doesn't already do that.